# Is the exponential function on Hermitian matrices injective?

Tags: matrices

[Exponential function and matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310087/exponential-function-and-matrices)

There's a proof here for real symmetric matrices.   But I don't know if it extends to Hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the proof there, replacing transpose with conjugate transpose. Note that the exponential function remains injective on the eigenvalues, because a Hermitian matrix has real eigenvalues.

Comment: But why is it that at the Wiki article on "Logarithm of a matrix."  There's an added condition that the matrix has non-negative real eigenvalues. To quote:logarithm is not unique, but if a matrix has no negative real eigenvalues, then it has a unique logarithm whose eigenvalues lie all in the strip {z ∈ C | −π < Im z < π}. This logarithm is known as the principal logarithm.

Comment: I think what's confusing you is that the exponential is injective on Hermitian matrices, but the logarithm is not single-valued. Note that these two are not incompatible...but the first condition implies that if you want to choose a *Hermitian* value for the logarithm, there is at most one.

Comment: There's this exercise in Horn and Roger though.  It asks me to prove that positive definite matrices have a unique Hermitian logarithm.  And I'm just bothered because my proof did not use the positive definite hypothesis.

Comment: Positive definite matrices are the only ones that can possibly have Hermitian logarithms. Said another way, whenever you exponentiate a Hermitian matrix you get a positive definite matrix. As an example, note that if you exponentiate a diagonal matrix of real numbers, you will get a diagonal matrix of positive numbers.

Comment: I'm starting to get it.  But what's wrong with this reasoning: if the matrix $A$ is Hermitian, then it has a logarithm that is a primary matrix function.  A logarithm that is a polynomial of $A$, hence, Hermitian.

Comment: Why is it a polynomial of $A$?

Comment: No.  I think my mistake was in assuming polynomial of a hermitian is hermitian.   I just realized that works only for real polynomial.  And that for example $p(x)=ix$ is skew-hermitian.   Anyway thanks for your help.   I'm correcting myself little by little.

Comment: @user100928 I see. No problem. I am still curious why it would be a polynomial of $A$, if you have time to explain.

Comment: The exponential of a matrix, because the exponential satisfies certain differentiability conditions, is, in a way, just determined through the exponential of the eigenvalues.   So you can use an interpolation formula to get a polynomial that does what the exponential function does to the eigenvalues.  The polynomial would depend on the matrix though.